# I have Jetpack installed on my wordpress, but Jetpack is offline, how can I open Jetpack?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, I installed wordpress using xampp, and recently installed Jetpack in wordpress, **but Jetpack is offline, I refer to the Internet information, use the notepad++ editor to add more define('JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG' to the wp-config.php file , true );** after this line, re-navigate once, and the result is that Jetpack is offline.

Internet reference sources:
https://zh-tw.jetpack.com/support/development-mode/
https://jetpack.com/support/development-mode/?site=localhost::wordpress

Questions are as follows:

1. Because there is no plug-in editor installed, is there no response to changing the plug-in code?
2. My URL is localhost so Jetpack is automatically offline?
3. To change to another URL, for example: http://xxxxx.com, will Jetpack not be offline?
4. Jetpack is offline, can it not protect the website?
5. Jetpack is offline, is there any other way to solve it? How can I open Jetpack?

The photo on the left uses the notepad++ editor, and an extra line of code is added to the picture, and the photo on the right is the execution result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5N2x.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NPmg.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's understand why your Jetpack is offline.

As per the documentation [here](https://jetpack.com/support/development-mode/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20turn%20on%20Offline,Happy%20blogging.) Jetpack goes offline for 2 reasons:

1. When you add `define( 'JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG', true );` to your wp-config.php file.
2. When it detects no period (.) In the URL. That means on http://localhost  it'll not work but on http://localsite.local it'll work. It needs to detect a period/dot (.) In the url.

In your case its both. You have that line in your code as well as the url without period.

Now here are answers to your questions:

1. You don't need any plugin editor if you're working on local. You can use anything like NPP or VS code etc. Also, you should bever edit jetpack or any plugin directly.
2. Yes, as i mentioned earlier.
3. If you change to another URL make sure you add a period (.) to it like http://something.local
4. No, when its offline it can't.
5. If you remove that line from wp-config.php and change the url to something with period it'll automatically go online.

**Pro Tip: Use [local](https://localwp.com/) for faster wordpress developments. It'll save ton of your time doing setups and all with xampp and it gives you control of php and mysql config per site. It setups wordpress on local machine in 3 clicks. Pretty easy.**

I hope i've solved all of your queries. If you have any other queries let me know.

Comment: so,delete this define( 'JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG', true ); ?

Comment: After I installed wordpress using xampp, I did not apply for any URL. After installing Jetpack at the beginning, it was offline after installing Jetpack.

Comment: Yes, remove that line. Use the local which is suggested in pro tip instead of XAMPP. It'll give you a url where your wordpress will work and jetpack too.

Comment: Do accept the answer if that worked for you. So that others can know what will work for them too.